# I want to pipe the output of one script to different script that will process the output of the first script independently?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

I have a very trivial bash script taking input from the user in the first step and then echo an output. I want to run the same script in different shells and let the first shell take input and echo its output and send it to the input of the other shell, and let the both of shells continue executing normally after that.

I have read many answers about exporting variables from shell to shell, like getting the name of the shell using tty and then redirect the output of the first terminal session to the second terminal session, that works only when executing single commands, but not mid executing of the two scripts.

This is the first script:

```sh
answer="n"
while [ "$answer" != 'y' ];do
    echo "enter the first value :"
    read first
    echo "the output is: "
    echo 6
    echo "enter value of A:"
    read  A
    echo "do you want to exit"
    read answer
done
```

The second script is the same:

```sh
answer="n"
while [ "$answer" != 'y' ];do
    echo "enter the first value :"
    read first
    echo "the output is: "
    echo 6
    echo "enter value of A:"
    read  A
    echo "do you want to exit"
    read answer
done
```

I want the first script running in the first terminal to output the number `6` and then pipe the number to the second script to be placed in the variable `first` and then let the two scripts continue executing in their respective terminals.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "another shell?"

Comment: What you're talking about is an RPC mechanism. Ones that are useful from shell exist -- named pipes are a useful construct to build them -- but generally, your time is going to be much better spent to think of a way to accomplish your goal without such a requirement.

Comment: And yes, if you're going to talk about a "second shell", the [mcve] you show us needs to actually have *two shells*.

Comment: @SeanBright like I have two terminal running on the same time

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes I tried to make fifo pipe, but I can't make them to work. I just started intenship-ish with my professor and I have been monkeying around in stackoverflow and bash textbooks for two days. but I must to do it that way

Comment: @CharlesDuffy and why is that?

Comment: Can your question be rephrased as "I want to pipe the output of one script to two different scripts that will process the output of the first script independently?".

Comment: @OmarKhalid, ...which "that"? The requirement that a [mcve] actually be complete enough to let us produce your problem ourselves? That's to make sure we actually understand what the specific technical problem you're asking about is, by letting us see it in action, and ensuring that we can test our answers (when the reproducer no longer fails, we know an answer is correct).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have just edited the question. Sorry for being vague.

Comment: @WalterA is it clearer now?

Comment: @OmarKhalid Not really. It looks like you want to have the read in script2 interrupted when the read in script1 is given input. Something like "there are two scripts both waiting for my response. When I answer one of them, I want that the other script will use this answer too.". If so, you can use smaller example scripts:
`read -p "Enter value" my_var; echo "var: $my_var"` and explain that the read in script 2 should terminate and show `$my_var` too. Perhaps explain why, so we can think of an easier alternative.

Comment: Why would you start both scripts in the first place when you haven't collected the data they're going to need? Do that up-front (and pass the data in the environment or by the command line, not via stdin) and the whole issue is moot. Which is to say -- is it *possible* to do what you're asking for? Sure, it's possible. Would any professional ever do it? I'd certainly hope not; the approach is inherently error-prone, since it depends on assumptions about flow control being identical between both scripts.

Comment: ...which is to say, the better answer is to redesign your process flow so you don't need to collect data "mid executing two scripts" at all.

Comment: @WalterA Yes that is exactly what I want.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know that it is impractical. But I was assigned to do that in that way. so if you could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A named pipe is the appropriate tool. Thus, in the first script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
my_fifo=~/.my_ipc_fifo
mkfifo "$my_fifo" || exit
exec {out_to_fifo}>"$my_fifo" || exit

answer="n"
while [ "$answer" != 'y' ];do
    echo "enter the first value :"
    read first
    echo "the output is: "
    echo 6                          # one copy for the user
    printf '%s\0' 6 >&$out_to_fifo  # one copy for the other program
    echo "enter value of A:"
    read  A
    printf '%s\0' "$A" >&$out_to_fifo
    echo "do you want to exit"
    read answer
done
```

...and in the second:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
my_fifo=~/.my_ipc_fifo
exec {in_from_fifo}<"$my_fifo" || exit  # note that the first one needs to be started first!

while IFS= read -r -d '' first <&"$in_from_fifo"; do
  echo "Read an input value from the other program of: $first"
  read -r -d '' second <&"$in_from_fifo"
  echo "Read another value of: $second"
  read -p "Asking the user, not the FIFO: Do you want to exit? " exit_answer
  case $exit_answer in [Yy]*) exit;; esac
done
```